# htaccess rewrite rules, or a PHP issue?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing a small web app mainly used just by myself so I'm not interested in fancy frameworks and page templating etc.

I need to be able to rewrite these urls:

```
/?page=parks
/?page=park&id=1
```

into

```
/parks
/park/1
```

Now, I have got very close with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

and this works for most of the pages I have, but if I do the URL /settings it breaks. If I echo $_GET['page'] I get "inc". I have no idea why. Is this a PHP issue, or are my rules wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` condition for this.

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That is caused by correct `RewriteCond` not getting applied to both rules.

Comment: Yes, but still don't understand why that worked well with all, and not with `settings` if it was not a problem with `settings` directory or `settings.php`